# Node.js Post Request Hanging

Tags: node.js, post, request

I have a ASP.Net API backend with user registration. I tried to make this post request using request module, and it works (I can see the data being written correctly to the database), but the browser just hangs and eventually shows a blank page.

```
/* POST Register */
router.post('/register/account', function(req, res, next) {
  process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
  request.post({
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
    url: 'https://localhost:44338/account/register',
    body:JSON.stringify({
      "email" : req.body.email,
      "password" : req.body.psw
    }), 
    function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  });
});
```

body should be a jwt generated token, I tested the post request on POSTMAN, it gives me a 200 OK status and even shows the token in the body. Any idea what's wrong? Ideally I want to go back to the index page with the token added to the cookie and/or header so I can do "authorized" requests afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `res.send()` to send response to the client browser.

```
router.post('/register/account', function(req, res, next) {
  process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
  request.post({
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'},
    url: 'https://localhost:44338/account/register',
    body:JSON.stringify({
      "email" : req.body.email,
      "password" : req.body.psw
    }), 
    function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      res.status(200).send(body);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the callback of your POST you need to use `res` to respond to the original request otherwise it will continue to hang. Something as simple as `res.status(200).send("Request successful")` should go right under the part where you have `console.log(body)`

You can see the Express.js API reference for `res` here https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Answer (score 0):

You must either return a response (using `res`) or call `next()` when you want that the request is processed further. If you don't that, the request wait ("hang").

In this case the request should be processed further when your internal HTTP request returns, so modify your callback. Also think about thee error case.